# Find domain, $f(x) =\log(\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2-8x+23)-\large\frac{3}{\log_{2}|\sin x|})$

Tags: functions

So as the question says finding domain of-

> $f(x) = \log(\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2-8x+23)-\large\frac{3}{\log_{2}|\sin x|})$

$\large f(x)=\log(\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2-8x+23)-\large\frac{3}{\log_{2}|\sin x|})$

What I did-

$\large\implies \log_{|\sin x|} (x^2 - 8x + 23) - \frac{3}{ (\log_{2} |\sin x|)} > 0$

$\large \implies \log_{|\sin x|} (x^2 - 8x + 23) - 3 \log_{|\sin x|} 2 > 0$

How to proceed further?

Comment: is the edit correct?

Comment: @Vikram I am little poor with the MathJax format, so couldn't do much.

Comment: I am asking if what I have done is correct according to your question?

Comment: @Vikram no! let me post a pic of my question.

Comment: @Vikram here is the snapshot of my question -http://goo.gl/UX9vwV

Comment: @Swetank did you saw my answer?

Answer (score 4):

To determine the domain of $log_a(b)$, you need to apply the constraints:
$$b > 0\\a>0 \land a \neq 1$$.

So let's apply them to the bases first:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
|\sin x| > 0\\ 
|\sin x| \neq 1\\
\end{matrix}\right. \iff \left\{\begin{matrix}
\sin x \neq 0\\ 
\sin x \neq \pm 1\\
\end{matrix}\right. \implies x \neq k\frac{\pi}{2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Passing to the arguments:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2 - 8x + 23 > 0\\
|\sin x| > 0
\end{matrix}\right. \iff \left\{\begin{matrix}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
x \neq k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{matrix}\right. \implies x \neq k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
This is clearly a subset of the previous solution, so until now we have
$$x \neq k\frac{\pi}{2}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{1}$$

It remains to apply the constraint to the first $\ln$:
$$\log_{|\sin x|} (x^2 - 8x + 23) - \frac{3}{\log_{2} |\sin x|} > 0\\
\frac{\ln(x^2-8 x+23)-3\ln2}{\ln|\sin x|}>0$$

Since $\ln|\sin x|$ is always negative (except when $|\sin x| = 1$, which we already excluded before) we can write:
$$\ln(x^2-8 x+23)-3\ln2<0\\
\ln(x^2-8 x+23)<\ln8\\
x^2-8 x+15<0\\
3 < x < 5$$
Putting this last result together with $(1)$ we get:
$$3 < x < 5 \land x \notin \left\{\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right\}$$

I plotted it with Desmos and got this:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ld5vmseh9y

Comment: @Swetank: Did you understand all the details? Is it enough to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\log\{\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2−8x+23)−\frac{3}{\log_2|\sin x|}\} &=
\log\{\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2−8x+23)+\log_{|\sin x|}\frac{1}{8}\} \\
&= \log\{\log_{|\sin x|}\frac{(x^2−8x+23)}{8}\} \\
&=\log\{\frac{\log\frac{(x^2−8x+23)}{8}}{\log|\sin x|}\}
\end{align}
$$
$$
=>\frac{\log\frac{(x^2−8x+23)}{8}}{\log|\sin x|} > 0\\ 
\text{In the above equation the denominator, } \log{|\sin x|} \text{, is always negative.}\\ \text{ So the numerator must also be negative, }
\log\frac{(x^2−8x+23)}{8} < 0 \\
\begin{align}
&=> \frac{x^2−8x+23}{8} < 1 \\
&=> {x^2−8x+23} < 8 \\
&=> {x^2−8x+15} < 0 \\
&=> (x-3)(x-5)<0 \\
\end{align} \\
x \in(3,5) \\
\text{Also we have a constraint on x from the initial equation : } |\sin x|>0,\ne 1 
\\ => x \in (0,2\pi) - \{\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\}
\\ x \in(3,5) - \{\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> $|\sin x|>0\\\implies x\ne n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{I}$
>
> ---
>
> $\log_2|\sin x|\ne0\\ \implies |\sin x|\ne1\\\implies x\ne (2n+1)\large{\frac\pi2}$
>   where $n\in\mathbb{I}$
>
> ---
>
> $x^2-8x+23>0\\\implies x\in\mathbb{R}$
>
> ---
>
> $\log_{|\sin x|}(x^2-8x+23)-\large\frac{3}{\log_{2}|\sin x|}>0 \\\implies 
> \log_{|\sin x|}(x^2-8x+23)-\large\log_{|\sin x|}8>0\\\implies
> \large{\log_{|\sin x|}(\frac{x^2-8x+23}8)>0}\\\implies
>  \frac{x^2-8x+23}8<1\\\implies
> x^2-8x+23<8\\\implies
> x^2-8x+15<0\\\implies
> x\in(3,5)$
>
> ---

Combining all $$\LARGE x\in(3,5)-\{\pi,\frac32\pi\}$$

Comment: sorry but need more help..